# Android java thread sleep sample

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I'm doing a simple animation app in Android. This is the scenario. I have a button and 4 textviews. When the user clicks the button, the first textview should begin animating (blinking effect) and next the second textview and so on. This is what I've tried so far:

```
 @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    btGo.setEnabled(false);
    glowCircuit2();
    glowCircuit3();
    glowCircuit4();


}

private void glowCircuit2() {

    new Thread(new Runnable()
    {

        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            while (!Thread.interrupted())
                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() // start actions in UI thread
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void run()
                        {   
                            // this action have to be in UI thread
                            tvCircuit2.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 
                                    R.drawable.activecircuit, 0, 0); 
                            tvCircuit2.startAnimation(animBlink);

                        }
                    });
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e)
                {
                    // ooops
                }
        }
    }).start(); // the while thread will start in BG thread

}

private void glowCircuit3() {

    new Thread(new Runnable()
    {

        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            while (!Thread.interrupted())
                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() // start actions in UI thread
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void run()
                        {   
                            // this action have to be in UI thread
                            tvCircuit3.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 
                                    R.drawable.activecircuit, 0, 0); 
                            tvCircuit3.startAnimation(animBlink);
                        }
                    });
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e)
                {
                    // ooops
                }
        }
    }).start(); // the while thread will start in BG thread

}

private void glowCircuit4() {

    new Thread(new Runnable()
    {

        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            while (!Thread.interrupted())
                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() // start actions in UI thread
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void run()
                        {   
                            // this action have to be in UI thread
                            tvCircuit4.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 
                                    R.drawable.activecircuit, 0, 0); 
                            tvCircuit4.startAnimation(animBlink);
                        }
                    });
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e)
                {
                    // ooops
                }
        }
    }).start(); // the while thread will start in BG thread

}
```

I'm getting the blinking effect but I'm getting the simultaneous effect. What I want is to wait for each textview to animate, not animate at the same time. Do you have any clever idea to do this? Help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: HINT: to achieve that you must call `glowCircuit3()` from within `glowCircuit2()`

Comment: You have not done any coding for waiting for threads to do animation one by one. There are multiple ways to achieve this, you should read the how to `join()` on threads. Other advanced way to do the same by using `Barriers`.

Comment: @sakura nope, I have done the blinking animation using xml. So what I wanna do now is to wait for the textview to display before the next textview to appear.

Comment: @PC. I've done that but I still get the same

Answer (score 2):

you are using Threads here, you never know which thread gets priority first and which will get started. I suggest you to using handler, create different message id to send empty message to handler, Android do something like this :

```
 @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    btGo.setEnabled(false);
    handler.sendEmptyMessage(1);


}

Handler handler = new Handler(){
    onHandle(Messsage msg)
    {
        switch (msg.what)
        {
            case 1 : glowCircuit2();
            handler.sendEmptyMessage(2);
            break;
            case 2: glowCircuit3();
            handler.sendEmptyMessage(3);
            break;
        }

    }
};


private void glowCircuit2(){

    tvCircuit2.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0,R.drawable.activecircuit, 0, 0); 
    tvCircuit2.startAnimation(animBlink);

}
```

Comment: Thanks. So where will I put this?

Comment: So I will put this in a method? I'm kinda confused sorry,.

Answer (score 0):

change your code

```
  glowCircuit2();
  glowCircuit3();
  glowCircuit4();
```

to this

```
  animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            glowCircuit2();
        }
    });

   animation1.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            glowCircuit3();
        }
    });

    animation2.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            glowCircuit4();
        }
    });
```

like this code start your third animation on second animation end and start fourth animation on third is end.